# About developing an ERP software AppEngine-based

Tags: java, google-app-engine

A few months ago I created a **shop manager** software for one of our customers.

One of the requirements was Adobe ColdFusion. Nevertheless, I came up with a really nice product, simple and fast, a few nice ideas and some positive feedbacks.
Now I think I am ready for letting "bigger" customers see my project.

I prefer not to write that next version in ColdFusion, I'm looking for something much more scalable and reliable.

The cloud computing, actually, is making me really curious! In particular, **Google AppEngine** seems to have all I need:

- I know Java
- I could start from scratch, without paying anything
- It's Google, what's more reliable than it?

I made a few helloworld-s, looking for the best technology to use.

GWT is really nice, but my dev team loves html+css "page centric" apps, so I think it would be a too high jump. Instead of it I was considering:

- Spring MVC 3.x
- Objectify 4 (as a persistence manager, instead of JDO/JPA)

My questions are:

1. Based on your experiences, **do you think that GAE is suitable for developing and hosting a "shop manager" software**, which will manage tables (CRUD), make reports, and so on? My projects is really simple.
2. Do the two technology I mentioned are good and enough for such a project? What will I need in addition?

Comment: offtopic: by ERP you mean Enterprise Resource Planning? The scale of your app doesnt fit in the definition of this term

Comment: Hint: Use Groovy and Grails (or the Gaelyk framework: http://gaelyk.appspot.com/). It's much faster and more flexible than just straight spring MVC (which is also nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an pretty standard shop, using: Appengine + Spring + Groovy + Objectify (and backbonejs + google closure templates for client side)

And from my experience I can say:

- It's possible :)
- Such system requires a lot of transactions - it's possible, but not so trivial using appengine. There is a lot of transactions, and a lot of work
- Reports is better to prepare on background (taskqueue/cron/prospectivesearch), and it's hard to prepare 'on-demand' or custom reports (actually it's must be done on background anyways)

I'm happy with my current implementation, but I see that using an standard RDBMS fits much better for this type of projects.

PS And also, you can take a look at [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/), I didn't tried it yes, but seems that it's good thing too and it have PostreSQL as service

Comment: Standard RDBMS can be used with GAE http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-cloud-sql-your-database-in-cloud.html